# When and when doesn't success: value executes in jQuery Ajax method? (Header location not changed)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm submitting a form using jQuery Ajax.

The data is submitted successfully but there's a little problem. When I add the commented statements in this code, the **success: function(){}** doesn't run (location is not changed).

**Q. 1** When I remove those statements, it runs. I don't understand this logic. When does it actually executes and how does checking for **xy** affects this?

Here's my **Ajax** code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
    **//FOLLOWING TWO LINES MAKES SUCCESS NOT RUN**
    //var **xy**= $("#digits").val();
    //if(xy!=""){
    $.ajax({
        url: "submitform.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#signupform').serialize(),         
        success: function(result){
            $(location).attr('href', 'login2.php');
            },
            error: function(){
            alert(error);
            }
        });
    //  }
    });
});
```

Here's concerned **input** tag:

```
 <form id="signupform" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="digits" type="text" name="phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your phone no." required />
......
```

**Q.2** When I write event.preventDefault(); to stop the default action of submit button, the **required** atrributes of input fields don't work. Why is it so? Can it be solved?

Comment: About Q1: Your form doesn't have an element with the id `digits` so `xy` will be empty, always.

Comment: About Q2: if you call `preventDefault`  on the submit button, then the default behaviour (initiating the submit) is prevented, so the input fields are not checked. You have to listen on the `submit` event of the `form` instead and prevent the default behaviour of this, because the submit event is send after the input element check and before the form is submitted.

Comment: Can it be corrected or do I need to use different approach? e.g PHP or JavaScript validation?

Comment: As I said, listen on the `submit` event of the `form` instead on `click` event of the `#button`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Sorry I posted the wrong input. Please check now, I've edited.

Comment: You mean something like $("form").submit(function(){....} instead of $("#button).click ?

Comment: @ObjectMatrix how? I think it is correct. Isn't it?

Comment: @ObjectMatrix all brackets are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Question 2:

If you call `preventDefault` for the event of the `click` on the submit button, then the default behaviour (initiating the submit) is prevented, so the input fields are not checked.

You have to listen on the `submit` event of the `form` instead and prevent the default behaviour of this, because the `submit` event is send after the input elements are checked and before the `form` is submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signupform").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //FOLLOWING TWO LINES MAKES SUCCESS NOT RUN**
    //var **xy**= $("#digits").val();
    //if(xy!=""){
    $.ajax({
      url: "submitform.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#signupform').serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        $(location).attr('href', 'login2.php');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
    //  }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's working fine. But what is "e" here? What does it take? Could you please explain?

Comment: @VikasKumar the first argument passed to the callback of event listener is the event object.

Comment: What is an event object?

Comment: For such questions you should first consult the documentation: [Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Answer (score 1):

When you use jquery ajax there is two types of result:

400 - OK status which be capture by the success function
402 or 500 are internal errors and those will be capture by the error function.

Now, in your error function youre trying to print an error variable that does not exist.

Also, when you use preventDefault you have pass variable that handles de event too cancel.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to alert("error") and it's displaying error now. But why is it showing this error?

Comment: I see in your form that you have the enctype attribute. are you attempting yo upload files in that form ?